# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Code:

```
Mockito.when(mongoRepo.findByIdAndIsDeleted(objId, false)).thenReturn(responseObj);
// here mongoRepo is MongoRepository and objId is UUID
```

When I run the test case I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

I also tried some other ways but no luck

Second example I tried:

```
Mockito.when(mongoRepo.findByIdAndIsDeleted(any(), anyBoolean())).thenReturn(responseObj);
// here mongoRepo is MongoRepository
```

The third example I tried:

```
 Mockito.when(mongoRepo.findByIdAndIsDeleted(any(UUID.class), Mockito.eq(false))).thenReturn(responseObj);
// here mongoRepo is MongoRepository
```

I'm getting the same exception.
Any help would be appreciated!!

I'm using MockitoJUnitRunner

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception, and a complete, runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Mokito provided an additional explanation for this error and printed the explanation in the run log.
Or you could check if the Matcher method is referenced correctly, some methods with the same name return Matcher for different purposes?